# How to read and update multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 10 txt files in Debug\Tests\Text\ (10 txt files). I need to write a program to open all 10 files and updated every single file. I'm not sure how to do it. Now, I'm actually reading the folder and getting the file name and storing the file name in an array. Below is my code:

```
private void getFilesName()
{
    string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"Tests\Text");

    //looping through the folder and get the fileNames
    for (int i = 0; i<fileArray.Length; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fileArray[i]); // I'm doing this is to double check i manage to get the file name.
    }

}
```

After doing this, it do read all the text file name, but the challenge now is for me to access the filename and updating every file in it. I have also created another method just for updating the values in the txt files, below is the code:

```
private bool modifySQLFile()
{
    string destFileName = @"Tests\Text\" // I need the fileName? 
    string[] fileTexts = File.ReadAllLines(destFileName);
    int counter = 0;

    //Processing the File
    foreach(string line in fileTexts)
    {
        //only read those non-comments line
        if(line.StartsWith("--") == false)
        {
            //Start to replace instances of Access ID
            if(line.Contains(Variable) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(Variable, textBox2.Text);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    //check if file exists in the backup folder
    if(File.Exists("Tests\\Text\\file name "+ textBox1.Text +".sql") == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This file already exist in the backup folder");
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        //update the file
        File.WriteAllLines(destFileName, fileTexts);
        File.Move(destFileName, "Tests\\Text\\file name"+ textBox1.Text +".sql");
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider updating your question with some more details like what you want to update, how the text looks like and what criteria, etc ..? if possible add an example.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` inside an ASP.NET application seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be passing the filename variable from the loop to the method.

In order to do what you want, add a parameter to the method:

```
private bool ModifySQLFile(string filename)
{
    string[] fileTexts = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    // ...
}
```

Then call the method with this parameter:

```
for (int i = 0; i<fileArray.Length; i++)
{
    ModifySQLFile(fileArray[i]);
}
```

But in general you really don't want to treat a formal language as plaintext like you do. It's very easy to break the SQL like that. What if the user wanted to replace the text "insert", or replaces something with "foo'bar"?

Answer (score 1):

First, implement one (`file`) modification:

```
private bool modifySQLFile(String file) {
  // given source file, let´s elaborate target file name
  String targetFile = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
    String.Format("{0}{1}.sql", 
      Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), 
      textBox1.Text));

  // In case you want a back up 
  //TODO: given source file name, elaborate back up file name 
  //String backUpFile = Path.Combine(...); 

  // Check (validate) before processing: do not override existing files
  if (File.Exists(targetFile)) 
    return false;

  //TODO: what if back up file exists? Should we override it? skip?  

  // if line doesn't start with SQL commentary -- 
  // and contains a variable, substitute the variable with its value 
  var target = File
    .ReadLines(file)
    .Select(line => (!line.StartsWith("--") && line.Contains(Variable)) 
       ? line.Replace(Variable, textBox2.Text)
       : line);

  // write modified above lines into file
  File.WriteAllLines(targetFile, target);

  // In case you want a back up 
  // Move file to backup
  //File.Move(file, backUpFile); 

  return true;  
}
```

Then call it in the loop:

```
  // enumerate all the text files in the directory
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles("@"Tests\Text", "*.txt");
    //TODO: you may want filter out some files with .Where
    //.Where(file => ...);

  // update all the files found above
  foreach (var file in files) {
    if (!modifySQLFile(file))
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} already exist in the backup folder", file));
  }
```

Please, do not do:

- Use *Magic values*: what is `@"Tests\Text\"` within your `modifySQLFile`
- Mix UI `MessageBox.Show(...)` and logic: `modifySQLFile` returns `true` or `false` and it's caller who can display message box.
- Materialize when it's not required (`Directory.GetFiles`, `File.ReadAllLines`)

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Bychenko , thanks for your help. However, if i was to copy the (10 text file) into a new folder call backup, and the modifySQL() will update the files in the backup folder leaving the original file untouch. How can it be done?

Comment: @Stella: As far as I can see, the original file are left intact (original files are  `*.txt` ones while target files are `*.sql`). In case you, however, want a separated back up files, just add some logic to `modifySQLFile`: you have to *elaborate* backup file name, check (if necessary) for back up file *existence*, and *move/copy* file to back up.

Comment: private void copyFile() // need to take it the file name
        {
            string targetPath = @"SQL Scripts\\Station Specifics SQL Scripts\\Backup";
            string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, ""); // the "" need to be the filename
  
            //Check if the dir exist
            if(!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                //Create the dir
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            //Copy the file to destination 
            File.Copy(fileName, destFile, true); //not sure how for this copy.
        }

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to edit the files in parallel. With threads you can parallelize work.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        new Thread(UpdateFileThread).Start(fileArray[i]);

    private void UpdateFileThread(object path)
    {
        string filePath = (string)path;
        //ToDo: Edit file
    }
```

In your case you would create 10 Threads. That solution works, but is a bad pattern if you have to deal with more than 10 files.

Comment: Why bad for more than 10 files? Why did you introduce threads? What problem will that solve?

Comment: Instructions were unclear. There is no real question. I thought he would likes to edit several files at the same time.

Comment: @CodeCaster Because the threadpool is limited and they have a bad scaling. (If you create backups, I guess there are more than hunderds of files)

Comment: The problem is that you pretty much never should use `Thread` in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Below i have posted the real time code ,which  i have used project

```
protected void btnSqlfinder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    //Defining the path of directory where all files saved  
    string filepath = @ "D:\TPMS\App_Code\";  
    //get the all file names inside the directory  
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);  
    //loop through the files to search file one by one   
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)  
    {  
        string sourcefilename = files[i];  
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(sourcefilename);  
        string sourceline = "";  
        int lineno = 0;  
        while ((sourceline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
        {  
            lineno++;  
            //defining the Keyword for search  
            if (sourceline.Contains("from"))  
            {  
                //append the result to multiline text box  
                TxtResult.Text += sourcefilename + lineno.ToString() + sourceline + System.Environment.NewLine;  
            }  
            if (sourceline.Contains("into"))  
            {  
                TxtResult.Text += sourcefilename + lineno.ToString() + sourceline + System.Environment.NewLine;  
            }  
            if (sourceline.Contains("set"))  
            {  
                TxtResult.Text += sourcefilename + lineno.ToString() + sourceline + System.Environment.NewLine;  
            }  
            if (sourceline.Contains("delete"))  
            {  
                TxtResult.Text += sourcefilename + lineno.ToString() + sourceline + System.Environment.NewLine;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This code will fetch the multiple files in the given directory,and show the lines as per the keyword in a separate text.

But you can easily change as per your requirement,Kindly let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to OP's question?